# Worklight LDAP Error

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst

When trying the LDAP sample project provided by Worklight, I get the following error:

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: Adapter 'DummyAdapter'
>   does not exist [project module_23_2_LDAPLoginModule] [ERROR   ]
>   FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error
>   message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request 
>   [project module_23_2_LDAPLoginModule]Adapter 'DummyAdapter' does not
>   exist, User Identity {SubscribeServlet=null, LDAPRealm=null,
>   wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null,
>   wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:rtm5uf72muh56gak3ms4gvvt42,
>   loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule),
>   wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null,
>   wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null,
>   myserver=(name:776c1909-3ae4-45b5-a029-f0372b507a7d,
>   loginModule:WeakDummy),
>   wl_anonymousUserRealm=(name:776c1909-3ae4-45b5-a029-f0372b507a7d,
>   loginModule:WeakDummy)}. [project module_23_2_LDAPLoginModule]
>
> com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter

In order to make it work, what values do I need to change. I want to use my IBM LDAP server.

Thanks..Johnson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least by reading the error message, it is pretty clear.

Did you make sure to also deploy the adapter and not just the application?
In your Worklight project, find the adapters folder. Open it. Then, right-click on the adapter folder within and select `Run As > Deploy Worklight adapter`.

Try the application again and see if it works, or if there are other errors displayed.

I suggest that instead of jumping right into what you want to do in your app, first learn the basics. [Review the IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/), from the top.

Comment: Hello Idan, Thanks for you quick response!! Sorry forgot to deploy the adopter. Now I am getting the below error.                         
[WARNING ] FWLSE0138W: LdapLoginModule authentication failed. Reason 'javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(Unknown Source)
I want

Comment: Here as well, the error is as written. Did you make sure to try and login with credentials that actually exist on the server-side so that the authentication will pass? read the LDAP training material and read the LDAP topic in the IBM Worklight Knowledge Center. Once you are versed with that, try again. This question has been answered, please mark as Answered.

Comment: Can I have the link for Knowledge Center ?

Comment: http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A/product_family_welcome.html